# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Class**'

Tags: c++, ordenamiento

estoy haciendo un programa que ordena una lista de 3 formas distintas (por método selección, burbuja y shell). Me sale el siguiente error

```
Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Animal**'
```

y

```
void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

en estas líneas

```
                            seleccion=ordSeleccion(a,n);

                            burbuja=ordBurbuja(a,n);

                            shell=ordShell(a,n);
```

de este código

```
                        int opcbus,a,n,seleccion,burbuja,shell;

                      do{
                      cout<<"Elija el método de ordenamiento a utilizar \n 1) Metodo seleccion \n 2) Metodo Burbuja \n 3) Metodo Shell \n 4) Regresar \n"<<endl;
                      cin>>opcbus;
                      switch (opcbus)
                      {
                        case 1:
                            seleccion=ordSeleccion(a,n);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            burbuja=ordBurbuja(a,n);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            shell=ordShell(a,n);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;          
                      case '5':             
                      break;
```

estos son mis ordenamientos

```
        void ordSeleccion (Animal *a[], int n){
            int indiceMenor,i,j;
            Animal *aux;
            for (i=0;i<n-1;i++){        
                indiceMenor=i;
                for (j=i+1;j<n-1;j++)
                if(a[j]->getNombreAnimal()>a[indiceMenor]->getNombreAnimal())
                indiceMenor=j;
                if (i!=indiceMenor){
                    aux=a[i];
                    aux=a[indiceMenor];
                    a[indiceMenor]=aux;
                }
            }
        };

        void ordBurbuja (Animal *a[], int n){
            int interruptor=1,pasada,j;
            Animal *aux;
            for (pasada=0;pasada<n-1&&interruptor;pasada++){
                interruptor=0;
                for (j=0;j<n-pasada-1;j++)
                if(a[j]->getNombreAnimal()>a[j+1]->getNombreAnimal()){                      
                interruptor=1;  
                aux=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1];
                }
            }
            cout<<"Los animales en orden son:\n"<<endl;
        };

        void ordShell (Animal *a[], int n){
            int intervalo,i,j,k;
            Animal *aux;
            intervalo=n/2;
            while(intervalo>0){
                for (i=intervalo;i<n;i++){
                    j=i-intervalo;
                    while (j>=0){
                        k=j+intervalo;
                        if (a[j]->getNombreAnimal()<=a[k]->getNombreAnimal())
                        j=1;
                        else{
                            aux=a[j];
                            a[j]=a[k];
                            a[k]=aux;
                            j-=intervalo;
                        }
                    }
                    intervalo=intervalo/2;                  
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: `ordSeleccion, ordBurbuja, ordShell` son de tipo `void`, que valor recibirán `seleccion, burbuja, shell`?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema.

Los errores son claros como el cristal e indican con total precisión tu problema; tal vez se te escape el significado por estar en inglés, permíteme traducirlos:

> ```
> Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Animal**'
> ```

> ```
> Conversión no válida de 'int' a 'Animal**'
> ```

El compilador te está indicando que no puede convertir un entero (`int`) en un puntero a un puntero a `Animal`. Lo cuál es obvio, un `int` no es un `Animal`.

Esto te estará pasando al llamar a las funciones `ordSeleccion`, `ordBurbuja` y
`ordShell` cuyas firmas son:

- `void ordSeleccion (Animal *a[], int n)`
- `void ordBurbuja (Animal *a[], int n)`
- `void ordShell (Animal *a[], int n)`

Y que has llamado de la siguiente manera:

- `seleccion=ordSeleccion(a,n);`
- `burbuja=ordBurbuja(a,n);`
- `shell=ordShell(a,n);`

Siendo `a` y `n` ambas variables de tipo `int`, pues las has declarado como tal en:

```
int opcbus,a,n,seleccion,burbuja,shell;
```

Así  pues, mientras que `n` coincide con el tipo del segundo parámetro de tus funciones, la variable `a` no coincide siendo ésta `int` y el primer parámetro siendo `Animal *a[]` (puntero a arreglo de `Animal`).

En cuanto al segundo error:

> ```
> void value not ignored as it ought to be
> ```

> ```
> El valor void no es ignorado y debería serlo
> ```

En C++ `void` significa "*vacío*"<sup>1</sup>, cuando quieres que una función no devuelva valores le indicas que el retorno de la función está vacío haciendo que devuelva `void`, de esa manera el compilador sabe que no debe esperar ningún valor de la función y puede ignorar su retorno... sin embargo le dices una cosa al compilador y actúas de manera opuesta a lo que dices, recordemos la firma de las funciones `ordSeleccion`, `ordBurbuja` y
`ordShell`:

- `void ordSeleccion (Animal *a[], int n)`
- `void ordBurbuja (Animal *a[], int n)`
- `void ordShell (Animal *a[], int n)`

En todas ellas le dices al compilador: "No te preocupes, no pienso devolver nada con estas funciones", pero acto seguido en el código:

- `seleccion=ordSeleccion(a,n);`
- `burbuja=ordBurbuja(a,n);`
- `shell=ordShell(a,n);`

Le dices al compilador: "Lo que sea que devuelve la función, me lo guardas en estas variables de tipo `int`", el compilador está confuso y se niega a seguir compilando: "*¿En qué quedamos? ¿¡debo o no debo ignorar el retorno de esas funciones!?*"

#### Solución.

Pasa un puntero a un puntero a `Animal` como primer parámetro a las funciones `ordSeleccion`, `ordBurbuja` y
`ordShell` y no las pongas a la derecha de una asignación.

---

<sup>1</sup>Eso es lo que significa en Inglés, que *casualmente* es lo mismo que significa en C++.